# Compiling a fabric mod yeilds the error "Unsupported class file major version 63"

Tags: java, minecraft

When I try to compile my fabric mod in intellij with gradle it fails during the :remapJar task and gives the error `Unsupported class file major version 63` I'm pretty sure that class file major versions only go up to 61 so I am very confused about this error. Any help would be amazing. I'm happy to give additional details if necessary.

Comment: version 63 is Java 19

Comment: ok but is there any way to fix this issue, I need to use java 17

Answer (score 1):

1. Try and use JDK17 if you're using the newest gradle version
2. Use Loom's "0.12-SNAPSHOT" version instead of the current one

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution of this error :-

[Unsupported class file major version 63](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhRJ0.jpg)

soo just go at your project folder and then open :-

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper-properties

change this :-

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

To This :-

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

and then your issue get solved